# Can't get data out of FTDI FT201X using i2c

Tags: c#, usb, i2c, ftdi

I have a project using the FTDI FT201X as a USB to i2c slave and the i2c master is an AVR microcontroller. I'm using WPF Core 3.1 C# on a Windows 10 machine. Basically, everything with the FTDI chip works fine except I can't successfully get data sent from the PC to the FTDI chip no matter what I try. The D2XX Write function says it was successful and returns no error, but there is never any data in the buffer when I try to read.

I've since written a small test program in an attempt to isolate the issue but the problem remains. Basically, when a button is clicked we open the device by serial number, we write a command to the device's buffers, handshake with the AVR to let it know to read and then wait for the AVR to drive a handshake pin low meaning it has received the data.

```
public class USBLibrary
{
    byte targetDeviceCount = 0;
    FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;
    public FTDI connectedUSBDevice;

    // Called from button click event
    public void ConnectUSB()
    {
        bool isOK = true; 
        byte numOfBytes = 1;
        uint bytesWritten = 0;
        bool usbInPinIsHigh = false;        // Tracks USB In Pin
        byte lowMask = 0b00010000;          // CBUS 0 is output (4-7), all pins low (0-3) (Default Setting)
        byte highMask = 0b00010001;         // CBUS 0 is output (4-7), CBUS 3 is high
        byte inPinMask = 0b00001000;        // AND with pin states to get input pin value (Bus3)
        byte pinStates = 0;                 // Used to get the current pin values
        double timeout = 0;

        // Create new instance of the FTDI device class
        connectedUSBDevice = new FTDI();

        // Determine the number of FTDI devices connected to the machine
        ftStatus = connectedUSBDevice.OpenBySerialNumber("P00001");

        /*** Write to Device ***/
        byte[] firmwareCmd = new byte[numOfBytes];

        firmwareCmd[0] = 128;       // 128 is Get Firmware Command
        // firmwareCmd[1] = 61;        // Just Testing

        // Write Firmware Command to Tx buffer
        ftStatus = connectedUSBDevice.Write(firmwareCmd, numOfBytes, ref bytesWritten);
        Trace.WriteLine(bytesWritten);

        // Handshake with Device
        isOK = DeviceHandshake(lowMask, highMask, inPinMask);

        // Check if handshake failed
        if (isOK == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        Task.Delay(10);

        // Wait until message is sent
        while ((usbInPinIsHigh == false) && (timeout <= 1000))
        {
            Task.Delay(1);

            // Check for USB In pin to go high. Signals FW transfer is complete and to retrieve.
            ftStatus = connectedUSBDevice.GetPinStates(ref pinStates);

            // Is input pin high or low?
            if ((pinStates & inPinMask) == inPinMask)       // In pin high
            {
                usbInPinIsHigh = true;                      // Means uC finished sending data
            }

            timeout++;
        }

        // TEST: displays timeout amount for testing
        Trace.WriteLine("Timeout=" + timeout);

        ftStatus = connectedUSBDevice.Close();
    }
}
```

NOTE: For this code, I've taken out a lot of the error checking code for clarity. Also, the handshake code is not shown because it shouldn't be relevant: raise output pin, listen for AVR to raise output pin, lower output pin, listen for AVR to lower output pin.

On the AVR side, we simply poll for the FT201X's pin to go high and then handshake with the chip. Then we simply read. The read function always returns 0.

I doubt the problem is with i2c as there are 3 IO Expander chips controlling LEDs and buttons and we can read and write to those fine. Further, the FT chip has a function called Get USB State where you can check to see the device's status by sending the command and reading the result via i2c. When I do this, I always get back the correct 0x03 "Configured" state. So we can read from the chip via i2c.

There's also a function that will return the # of bytes in the buffer waiting to be read...when I do this, it always says 0 bytes.

And for good measure I replaced the chip with a new one in case it was bad and again we had the same results.

Is there anything I'm missing in terms of setting up the chip beyond using FT_Prog, like an initialization procedure or setting registers or something? Or do I need to somehow push the byte I write to the front of the queue or something before it can be read? Anybody seen anything like this before?

Given that I haven't affected the results, I'm either missing a key part in the process or something is wrong with their driver/version of the chip. It's been 3 weeks, I'm out of ideas, and my hair is patchy from ripping out large chunks. Please save my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Check by oscilloscope that your I2C master gives clock for your slave (FT201x). Try to control only I2C (rip off GPIO controls) and check if you can isolate problem that way. I suppose you are very familiar with [FT201X datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT201X.pdf). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check the latency timer setting. It’s described in this document, https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf. In section 3.3, you’ll find a section describing a scenario in which no data will be made available to the app.

“While the host controller is waiting for one of the above conditions to occur, NO data is received by our driver and hence the user's application. The data, if there is any, is only finally transferred after one of the above conditions has occurred.”

You can use the latency timer to work around it, if you’re hitting this. Try setting it to 1ms, its lowest value. If your data has a delimiter character, consider setting that as an event character and you might get even better results.

Answer (score 0):

Did this issue ever get resolved?

Experiencing the same issues with an FT200X except the function "bytes available" (0x0C) returns the correct byte count sent from the host PC, but can't read the actual bytes using the read procedure mentioned in the datasheet.

I have also several other I2C devices on the bus, working fine.